# How to create a MS Dynamics CRM app

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I would like to create a Visual Studio project to my Dynamics site. 
I'm using .NET and Javascript. My target is create a component (html + javascript/angular/...) and add this component into my dynamics page layout (or somewhere in dynamic site to see my UI).

My project has Back-end as well which using web API and get Dynamics CRM metadata by Client Object Model and send result to the component.
I finished my backend API and client HTML component. But I don't know how to install my app and show my component into my Dynamic site.

Could anyone share me some tutorials or demos related this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started... the general way to add things into CRM is via unmanaged or managed Solutions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334576.aspx.

The solution that contains everything is called the Default Solution. You can get to it by going to Settings > Customizations > Customize the System.

You can put your JavaScript code into one or more web resources. Then add them to a form and register them on the OnLoad, OnSave, or individual field OnChange events.

C# code goes in as a Plugin Assembly or a Custom Workflow Assembly. To register those, use the Plugin Registration Tool, which is available in the SDK.
Once your plugins are registered, you can add them to a solution and port them to other systems.

Comment: Yes, I see them. 
So, we need to bundle and mixim all solution code to one script file and upload to webresource, doesn't it? :)